# Data conversions from audio data to TPCircularBuffer and audio unit to filter Heart beat sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, filter, signal-processing

In my iOS application, using swift

i am getting audio from digital health device (BLE). In the form of audio data, to hear heart beats.

1. We have ADPCM decoded file. That we have decoded using ADPCM decoder.

[ADPCM Decoded file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xheuDhHFEXiRNiNkuY0RPC1785x6-vB3/view?usp=sharing)

We want to remove the background noise from it.

2.
For that, we apply low pass filter and high pass filter using apple's DSP code. We are getting float samples, after after filtering.

So, first question is Conversion of Data to float is correct ?

[Apple's DSP Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/applying_biquadratic_filters_to_a_music_loop)

```
      let samples = convertUInt8ToFloats(sampleData: audioData)
      let samples1 =  musicProvider.loadAudioSamples(samples: samples)    


func convertUInt8ToFloats(sampleData: Data) -> [Float] {
        
        let factor = Float(UInt8.max)
        let samples = sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
            UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: $0, count: sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        }
        var floats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: samples.count)
        for i in 0..<samples.count {
            floats[i] = Float(samples[i]) / factor
        }
        return floats
    }
```

In Apple's sample code they are loading assets like this, But i can not load assets like this, as i have raw audio file, is above convertUInt8ToFloats conversion same as below ?

```
    let asset = AVAsset(url: path.absoluteURL)
    
    let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
    
    guard let track = try await asset.load(.tracks).first else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let outputSettings: [String: Int] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 32,
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 1
    ]
    
    let output = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track,
                                          outputSettings: outputSettings)
    
    reader.add(output)
    reader.startReading()
    
    var samplesData = [Float]()
    
    while reader.status == .reading {
        if
            let sampleBuffer = output.copyNextSampleBuffer(),
            let dataBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
            
            let bufferLength = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(dataBuffer)
            let count = bufferLength / 4
            
            let data = [Float](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: count) {
                buffer, initializedCount in
                
                CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(dataBuffer,
                                           atOffset: 0,
                                           dataLength: bufferLength,
                                           destination: buffer.baseAddress!)
                
                initializedCount = count
            }
            
            samplesData.append(contentsOf: data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: There Is not enough detail to answer your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What is "uttering sound"? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Usually floating point audio samples are in the range -1...1. Are you certain your conversion to UInt8 here is correct?

Comment: @soundflix added code. Utter sound like noise high frequency sound

Comment: @RobNapier floating point samples are not in range of -1…1. It is coming different. I cast it into 0…255

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make sense. It creates a UInt8 called `unsignedData` and passes that to `filter` which takes a Double. As written, this shouldn't compile. Is this your actual code? (In any case, if you're getting complete white noise, that means you've messed up the data format. If you're getting high frequency noise overlaying good audio, that often means you're clipping (I would check that your clamping function is almost never actually firing; it shouldn't if you've tuned this correctly). I would suspect your `a` and `b` values, but you haven't given us enough to help you.

Comment: @RobNapier I am sorry I typed the code, so it was mistake. I have updated code. Yes, the getting white noise, over good audio. Code is compiling, but need to check clamping function, that it is correct or not. And for an and b values I am using band pass filter with 40 to 180 Hz.

Comment: Your data handling here doesn't make sense. What format are your samples in? Is it unsigned 0-255 or signed -128 to 127? (is this really 8-bit, 1 channel audio,?) Why do you convert to Double?

Comment: @RobNapier Samples come as rawData, we apply ADPCM decoder it takes int data, and gives back 2 bytes of unsigned int, (0 -255). 1 channel audio. We need o convert it the double to apply iir filters.

Comment: Is your IIR filter normalized to the same baseline value and range? (In this case, I assume the baseline is 127; it can't be zero?) Share the full filter in a form that we can run, including your values for the `a` and `b` coefficients. I don't think you're operating on these numbers in the right ranges.

Comment: @RobNapier should i provide Python script, would you please run and check. Here is a link, would you please check. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EtZaCJ1zqcj05TL4s9iHAGjaLbTKiRCA?usp=sharing

Comment: What are these files? What format are they in? What should they sound like? Are they ADPCM, or decoded ADPCM into LPCM? This is definitely not u16 ("2 bytes of unsigned int, (0 -255)"). Maybe it's s8 (if it's supposed to sound like wind). If you were going to play this with SoX or FFMPEG, what parameters would you use?

Comment: These are audio data captured files from BLE. 1 is in data format and 1 is in data format and 1 is in a lwav file. If I play wav file and apply the filter it audio is filtered rightly. When I play data file then filtered is applied not properly and utter sound comes. We thought that first check in python that it is giving desired result or not.

Comment: These files are ADPCM decoded file. Data file we play in player.

Comment: @RobNapier ADPCM decoded file takes Siged Int and returns unsigned int array of 2 elements

Comment: @RobNapier would you please check that latest update on question.

Comment: "If you were going to play this with SoX or FFMPEG, what parameters would you use?"

Comment: @RobNapier playing a raw audio which is ADPCM decoded file is played using "ffplay -f u8 -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i input" this format

Comment: In audacity also we can play the same file, with LinearPCM, 16 bit, Little endeien, 16000 sample rate

Comment: wait... is it 8-bit or 16-bit LE? Those are different formats. Playing it in either leads to extreme clipping, suggesting that that this is in neither format. You generally cannot just guess the format. You need to check the documentation of the device, and then check the documentation of your ADPCM decoder. What exact format do they accept and return? I really can't help you here if you do not know what audio format your data is in.

Comment: Hi, Actually ADPCM decoder gives converts to data in UInt8 bytes. So, we interprete it as 8 bit data format. Here is a ADPCM Decoder algorithm. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yJjYA-ot1XuuzCHCm-AFQxo_cqQN7Amv/view?usp=sharing It gives UInt8 byte in "decodedSample" function.

Comment: Actually i tried to play with ffplay -f s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i input2 this format, and i got good sound of heart beat. the format should be s16le.

Comment: Hi, @RobNapier updated latest code, I have downloaded apple's DSP code project, and applied filter in it, it is playing sound without noise. When i play the same file in my demo app, i could not able to play the same sound in audio engine. The reason i see is audio conversion from decoded data to float conversion. In apple's code they are converting like code snippet at last, and i am converting like  convertUInt8ToFloats is there any difference. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually i tried to play with ffplay -f s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i input2 this format, and i got good sound of heart beat. the format should be s16le.

This is all the information needed. You need to convert Data to SInt16 (i.e. s16le), and then SInt16 to Float.

Using the Apple sample code, this would be:

```
static func getAudioSamples(forResource: String,
                            withExtension: String) async throws -> (naturalTimeScale: CMTimeScale,
                                                                    data: [Float])? {
    
    guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: forResource,
                                     withExtension: withExtension) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Load raw data
    let rawData = try Data(contentsOf: path)

    // Convert raw data into [S16Int] as little-endian
    let sIntLEData = rawData.withUnsafeBytes {
        Array($0.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)).map(Int16.init(littleEndian:))
    }

    // Scale [SInt16] to [Float] in the range [-1, 1]
    let samplesData = sIntLEData.map { Float($0) / Float(Int16.max) }

    // Set the sample-rate
    let naturalTimeScale = CMTimeScale(16_000)

    // Return as expected by caller.
    return (naturalTimeScale: naturalTimeScale,
            data: samplesData)
}
```

You can then apply filters as in Apple's sample code.

To reverse the process, multiply rather than divide. You'll want to operate in the Int space and clamp to avoid crashing in cases where your algorithm might stray slightly outside the strict [-1, 1] range (which sometimes happens).

```
// This is safe if floatsArray has already been scrubbed to only
// "reasonable" values. It will crash if there are values outside
// the range of Int, infinity, or NaN.
floatsArray.map { Int16(clamping: Int($0 * Float(Int16.max))) }
```

If your algorithm may emit outrageous values outside the range of Int, or infinity or NaN, you can do some more work to deal with those values and avoid crashing, but this is going to create noise in your output, and you should really just make sure the input is normalized before converting.

Here's an example of a way to make it safe from crashes, however, if you want it:

```
// This is safe for any Float values, but it may be extremely noisy
// if the values are out of range.
let sInt16Array = floatsArray.map {
    let scaled = $0 * Float(Int16.max)
    let intValue = Int(exactly: scaled.rounded(.towardZero)) ?? 0
    return Int16(clamping: intValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    func applyFilterToData(decoded: Data, filterEnabled: Bool = true) -> Data {
    var lastData = Data()
    for decodedData in decoded {
        let unsignedData = UInt8(decodedData)
        let scaledInput = Double(unsignedData) / 128.0 - 1.0  // Assuming 0-255 range

        var filteredOutput: Double
        if filterEnabled {
            filteredOutput = iirFilterNew.filter(scaledInput)
        } else {
            filteredOutput = scaledInput
        }

        // Scaling output (adjust if needed)
        let scaledOutput = filteredOutput * 128.0 + 128.0
        let outputUInt8 = UInt8(clamping: Int(round(scaledOutput)))

        lastData.append(outputUInt8)
    }
    return lastData
}

// Improved conversion with clamping
func convertDoubleToUInt8(value: Double) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8(clamping: Int(round(value)))
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Sai for your answer. @Sai-Programmer. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @Sai-Programmer it made the defference but still the noise comes.